# how I can add a css file correctly to a php file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My css file import in the header of the html not work. It don't show any changes on the page. I have tried to add the type="text/css" to the link object of the html header but this has no effect.

login.php

```php
<?php

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link ref="stylesheet" href="login.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Test</p>
    <form class="form-signin">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Bitte anmelden</h1>
...
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Anmelden</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

login.css

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

p {
    background-color: chartreuse;
}

body {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: auto;
}
.form-signin .checkbox {
    font-weight: 400;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
...
```

How I can import the css file correctly. To change the design of the html site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has an error on line 12, you wrote "ref" which needs to be changed to "rel".

Your code will work if you fix this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change:

```
 <link ref="stylesheet" href="login.css">
```

to

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
```

you've typed ref and not rel in line 12

your css file is correct :)